# Where are .fxml files in Maven project with JavaFX dependency?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm pretty new to Maven and JavaFX so I'm assuming there's an easy answer, but I haven't been able to find it.

I want to create a GUI for my project, which I have as a maven project in IntelliJ. I was able to get a GUI to function as intended by adding `javafx-fxml` and `javafx-controls`. When wanting to try SceneBuilder I realized that the .fxml file was nowhere to be found.

Some sources say to look in the resources folder but that appears to be empty. Another says there is a second src folder(?) but if that's the case I can't find it.

Comment: The fxml files will be wherever you saved them, either from SceneBuilder or from your IDE. (Typically the best place to put them is `/src/main/resources`)

Comment: The project was originally a maven project, and upon adding dependencies and a class that extends Application, a GUI appears when I run the project. I never touched any fxml files. Does this mean there are no fxml files, i.e. fxml files aren't required for jfx to run?

Comment: So which fxml files are you trying to locate? Your question doesn’t really make sense.

Comment: I just edited my comment but, I was operating under the assumption that JavaFX needs .fxml files to run- so I was assuming there were some hidden away. Is this not the case?

Comment: No, that's not the case. What do you think the FXML files are doing that isn't done from the existing code?

Comment: I hardly know what they are doing in the first place, very new to JavaFX and quite new to programming in general. I think I'm starting to grasp the basics though- FXML is used to more easily format and style, while the controller contains what the components actually "do". I'm learning JFX from two different sources, one of which has taught basically exclusively FXML and the other not even mentioning it, so the rift has confused me.

Comment: I guess I copy pasted the dependencies but otherwise I don't know what you're talking about. I didn't know what String[]args meant in a main method meant when I started and I'm assuming trying to before I ran my first method would've confused me more. If there's something specific you're referencing I'd like to know because I obviously am trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your package name is `com.example`

Then your Application code is here `<project root>\src\main\java\com\example\App.java`

Place your FXML here `<project root>\src\main\resources\com\example\App.fxml`

Load your FXML using Java code

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("App.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

`App.java` as well as `App.fxml` are in the same package, therefore `getClass().getResource("App.fxml")` works fine